# How to increase the session lifetime in Symfony2?

Tags: php, session, symfony

I have a login with a remember checkbox.
I'm tring to set lifetime of session to 1 year if the remember checkbox is checked, but no matter what I tried, it doesn't work... Symfony profiler always say that session lifetime is 0.

That's what I tryed in my controller function:

```
$this->getRequest()->getSession()->set("gesaudit",array("login"=>true,"user"=>$user));

if($remember == "1"){
    $lifetime = new NativeSessionStorage();
    $lifetime->setOptions(array('cookie_lifetime' => 31557600));
}else{
    $lifetime = new NativeSessionStorage();
    $lifetime->setOptions(array('cookie_lifetime' => 0));
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Normal session lifetime can be managed, according to the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#session), via config.yml:

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_lifetime: 3600
```

To set the lifetime to a year: 3600*24*365 = 86400*365 = 31536000. Easy :).

This sets the session cookie lifetime to 1 hour. There are tons of other things you can configure, but that's why I included a link to the documentation.
If you insist on doing this manually, in a specific case/controller, then pass the options array to the controller. Perhaps that'll work instead of using the `setOptions` method: If your php.ini contains:

```
session.auto_start = 1
```

Then creating the `NativeSessionStorage` instance will automatically, and immediately create the session, with the default lifetime. Setting it afterwards will make little or no difference. Check your ini settings, or do:

```
$test = new NativeSessionStorage();
var_dump($test->isStarted())
```

If it dumps `true`, try:

```
$lifetime = new NativeSessionStorage(
    array(
        'cookie_lifetime' => 31536000
    )
);
```

Everything on sessions in Symfony2 can be found [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html).

If you are using Symfony2.4, there is a special section in the docs that deals with [remember-me functionality](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html), as Jakub Polák pointed out. The essence of it is that the checkbox has to be called `_remember_me`, that the config.yml has to define a `%secret%` value, and that you add (a tailored) version of this to your security.yml file:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        remember_me:
            key:      "%secret%"
            lifetime: 31536000
            path:     /
            domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
```

But the documentation explains this all, but you'll have to *"cruise"* the manual a bit. For example, if you want to specify different remember-me behaviour for specific sections, change the `main` in the yml snippet above, and add a `pattern` setting, as [explained here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/firewall_restriction.html). 
You'd probably best scan [the entire security section](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/index.html).

Comment: "Remember me" functionality is part of Symfony2 Security, therefore the correct documentation is: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html

Comment: Didn't read the question all that carefully. You're right, OP mentions remember me checkbox, will edit

Comment: I'm not using the security component. I'm tring to make my own bundle with my own controllers to check in any request if there are session or not. That's why I need to change the session lifetime "on the fly" when user log in. If the user check remember me, I need to set session lifetime to 1 year, else to 0. Is possible?

Comment: @Angel: Yes, as is explained in the security extension documentation. Using that would be the best way forward. It has functionality built in to set remember-me cookies for as long as you want/need, for specific parts of your project. It's _exactly_ what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I need to read more about that. I'll try to implement the functionality what you're talking about.

Comment: @Angel: quickly checked the docs on the `NativeSessionStorage` class. It can't set the `session.auto_start` option, so if your ini settings have auto_start set to true/1, then you can't use the `setOptions` method to change the lifetime. Just pass the options array to the constructor instead

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I tried to make something like `$lifetime = new NativeSessionStorage(array('cookie_lifetime'=>31557600));` and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It should be done in `security.yml` configuration file:

```
secured_area:
    pattern:  ^/yourpattern
    remember_me:
        key:      "%secret%"
        lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
        path:     /yourpath
        domain:   .yourdomain.com
```

You can find related documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html).