# Best way to handle ephemeral tokens when using SimplePreAuthenticator & PreAuthenticatedToken

Tags: php, symfony, security, authentication

I'm using the SimpleAuthentication feature as described here : http://symfony.com/doc/2.6/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html

The purpose is to provide an authentication through a token string passed as a query (get) parameter or a header. This token, let's call it **TemporaryAccessToken** to avoid confusion with the Sf2 token, is generated by a controller, sent to the user by email (not described here) and should be available for a limited amount of time (there's a `valid_until` `\DateTime` column in the dedicated entity).

For the record, when the protected page (by the `simple_user_account` firewall) is accessed the first time the authentication process goes like this :

- [SimplePreAuthenticationListener](https://github.com/symfony/security-http/blob/master/Firewall/SimplePreAuthenticationListener.php) is triggered
- Basically, [calls](https://github.com/symfony/security-http/blob/master/Firewall/SimplePreAuthenticationListener.php#L84) `MyAuthenticator->createToken()`
- Then [calls](https://github.com/symfony/security-http/blob/master/Firewall/SimplePreAuthenticationListener.php#L91) `AuthenticationManager->authenticate()`, which [calls](https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/master/Authentication/Provider/SimpleAuthenticationProvider.php#L37) `MyAuthenticator->authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)`

Problem is : once the user has been authenticated, and because I'm using `stateless: false` in the firewall configuration, the authentication process is not triggered again since there's already a valid Sf2 token in session.

I see 2 logic solutions but I can't figure out how to do this properly :

- make the session valid until the date which is set into my `TemporaryAccessToken.valid_until` column. Is there a way to achieve that "natively" ? (I saw that the `remember_me` firewall has a `lifetime` parameter)
- **or**, be able to re-check the TemporaryAccessToken validity (see the `if( $accessToken && $accessToken->isValid() )` line in my Authenticator)

`app/config/security.yml`

```
firewalls:
    simple_user_account:
        pattern:   ^/account/access
        stateless:  false
        simple_preauth:
            authenticator: app.security.simple_user_authenticator
        logout:
            path:   /logout_simple
            target: /
```

My authenticator class looks like :

```php
class SimpleUserAuthenticator implements SimplePreAuthenticatorInterface, AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var AccessTokenManager
     */
    private $accessTokenManager;

    /**
     * SimpleUserAuthenticator constructor.
     * @param AccessTokenManager $accessTokenManager
     */
    public function __construct(AccessTokenManager $accessTokenManager)
    {
        $this->accessTokenManager = $accessTokenManager;
    }

    public function createToken(Request $request, $providerKey)
    {
        $TemporaryAccessToken = $request->query->get('simple_user_token');
        if (!$TemporaryAccessToken) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException('No simple_user token found');
        }

        return new PreAuthenticatedToken(
            'anonymous',
            $TemporaryAccessToken,
            $providerKey
        );
    }


    public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
    {
        if( $token->getUser() instanceof SimpleUser )
        {
            $newToken = new PreAuthenticatedToken(
                $token->getUser(),
                $token->getCredentials(),
                $providerKey,
                array('ROLE_USER')
            );
            return $newToken;
        }

        $accessToken = $this->accessTokenManager->getRepository()->findOneByToken($token->getCredentials());
        if( $accessToken && $accessToken->isValid() )
        {
            $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($accessToken->getAccount()->getEmailCanonical());
            $newToken = new PreAuthenticatedToken(
                $user,
                $token->getCredentials(),
                $providerKey,
                array('ROLE_USER')
            );
            return $newToken;
        }
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        $response =  new RedirectResponse(
            '/login'
        );
        return $response;
    }

    public function supportsToken(TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return $token instanceof PreAuthenticatedToken && $token->getProviderKey() === $providerKey;
    }


}
```

Symfony2 version : 2.5.6

Comment: Anything unclear in my question ?

Comment: if you set `stateless: true` then you will need authenticate user each time he access firewall. But stateless firewall does not keep anything in session. If this information not useful for you, please, tell me directly, what you need. I'm not sure that understand you correctly.

Comment: That's the point, I want to use stateless: false to be able to log my user into the session (because he will be able to navigate to other pages after being authenticated, without having to passe the TemporaryAccessToken again). Problem is that, when it's done, it's done. On every subsequent request, I want to be able to see if my TemporaryAccessToken is still valid against a date which is stored in the entity that handle this token. The SimplePreAuthListenner is not triggered again, so is my SimpleUserAuthenticator.

Comment: Another solution would be to force the timeout which will be basically `TemporaryAccessToken.valid_until - now()` but not sure how to do that in the right way (and not sure it's the way to go...)

Comment: IMHO, checking that your token is valid has sense only when firewall is stateless. Another solution: properly configure your session cookies and set time when session cookie expired.

Comment: Good point. Regarding the cookie/session things, can you give me some hints to do that in the right way ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you need to use session, you can set `lifetime` under your config.yml session settings:

```
# config.yml
framework:

    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id: ~
        lifetime: 3600
```

You can change `lifetime` value to anything in seconds (it defaults to 3600 or 1 hour)

Also, you can try to [configure garbage collector](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#configuring-garbage-collection).

If this answer was not helpful, please, let me know.

Comment: Problem is that the cookie lifetime must be computed when the user is logged in

Comment: @foobar on each authentication new session file is created, afaik.

Comment: How would you dynamically set the cookie lifetime during the authentication workflow ?

Comment: @foobar maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23362701/how-to-increase-the-session-lifetime-in-symfony2, but have you tested my previous comment? After authentication new session should created with lifetime 3600, isn't it ?

Comment: No, when the session is created, the lifetime has to be calculated based on the current date and the `TemporaryAccessToken.valid_until` date.

Comment: This `valid_until` date is generated when the token is generated, not when it's consumed.
To illustrate that :
1) the token is generated today at 6pm, so it's valid until tomorrow 6pm
2) the user has to "consume" the token before tomorrow 6pm, if not, it cannot be used for the authentication
3) if he uses the token, let's say tomorrow at 4pm, then the session lifetime has to be 2 hours, which means that it cannot be fixed by a configuration value

Weird you say ? :)

Comment: @foobar I think, i figured what you need. What do you think about configuring two firewalls? on first firewall you get the key, that will be send to email, on second firewall you can authenticate via key and set in your authenticator actual `valid_until`

Comment: No, I'm afraid, it's not the use case. The TemporaryAccessToken is out of the question scope, the related key is sent by another emailing process.